# how do I find a undecidable subset of a set that's decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Given that Let S = {a | |a| is odd}. I know that since S is decidable, but does there exist a subset within S that is undecidable?

Comment: This is a dump of a homework problem. It has also been previously asked on this site.

Comment: Any set (even undecidable ones) are subsets of the set of all strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For every language $L$, the language $M = \{ 1^{2x+1} : x \in L \}$ is a subset of $S$.

Comment: thanks for the hint. If L contains all natural numbers, wouldn't M = {1} since 1 to any power will remain 1, and even though M is a subset of S, M only contains 1 and is decidable?

Comment: Here $1^{2x+1}$ is the string of length $2x+1$ consisting only of $1$s.

Comment: I am confused as to why a language with only odd number of 1s would be a subset of S. Am I misinterpreting the question by thinking that x must be a number?

Comment: Well, $S$ consists of all strings of odd length...